# vb.net - Sort datagridview column numerically

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I know this has been asked quite a few times, but i'm having issues with the solutions found on most other pages.

I have a single datagridview column that i want to be sorted by number (1,2,10 instead of 1,10,2)
Best i can see online, i need to convert the column or cell to an integer value type - but i'm not sure how to do so.

I've tried `grid.columns(4).valuetype = typeof(System.int32)`, and tried the same for cells individually.

Trying above always results in a "int32 is a type in 'system' and cannot be used as an expression" error - which i'm not sure about.

The data itself is obtained froma text file, and converted from string to integer when being added into the cell `datagrid_alltracks.Rows(shutupaboutlambda).Cells(4).Value = CInt(numstring))`

Comment: Is the gridview bound to a data source ?

Comment: Did you solve the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the grid is bound to a data source you could try 
`datatable.Columns.Add("ColumnName", GetType(Integer))`

Else you may need to use the `SortCompare` event on the gridview.
[See here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.sortcompare(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

Comment: Thank you. I used the SortCompare method you linked to and it works well. Sorry for the delay in marking this as answer.

Comment: thanks for voting up :) Glad it resolved your issue.

Comment: Since my datasource was an on-the-fly table, the first method worked fine for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can just set the DataGridView SortCompare Event to compare two integers (or two singles, or two doubles). Code wise (calling your datagridview "grid")

```
Private Sub grid_SortCompare(sender as Object, e as DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs) Handles grid.SortCompare
    e.SortResult = CInt(e.cellvalue1).CompareTo(CInt(e.cellValue2))
    e.Handled = True
End Sub
```

if you are doing single or double variables, use CSng or CDbl instead of CInt

```
    e.SortResult = CSng(e.cellvalue1).Compareto(CSng(e.CellValue2)
```

You can do more fancy sorting if you want, You basically need to know that e.SortResult is Positive, Negative or Zero, and your cells are sorted according to that result (Positive keep order, negative reverse order, Zero - matched - do nothing (yet)). The current row index(s) and column are available in the e arguments so you can also compare adjacent column data if the current cells are matched)

Comment: And in case of mixed columns, you may want to test e.Column.Name, in order to differentiate sort mode by column.

Comment: Worked like a charm ! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm coming to the party late, but I found that I once I had added the data, I needed to convert the desired columns to have a data type.

I'm adding data like the following:

```
DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New String() {CInt(recordnum), True, "play", wszName.ToString, qiOffset.ToString, value.ToString, qiLength.ToString})
```

Then, after all the data has been added, I then do a simple loop and convert the column, where I can then sort it. It's set up so you can do multiple columns if need be.

```
Dim colnum As Integer
colnum = 0 ' set this as your column to change the data type to

For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim d As Double = Double.Parse(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(colnum).Value.ToString())
    DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(colnum).Value = CInt(d)
    DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(colnum).ValueType = GetType(Double)
Next
```

Sorting can work for whatever column you adjusted. In this case, it's column 4.

```
DataGridView1.Sort(DataGridView1.Columns(4), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)
```